# Error On mockMvc.perform. Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockmvc

My Test Controller
This is a Groovy class with Spock Framework.

```
class LookupControllerSpec extends Specification {

     def lookupService = Mock(LookupService)
     def lookupController = new LookupController(lookupService)

     MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(lookupController).build()

     def "should return a single lookup record when test hits the URL and parses JSON output"() {
         when:
         def response = mockMvc.perform(get('/api/lookups/{lookupId}',2L)).andReturn().response
         def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.contentAsString)

         then:
         1 * lookupService.fetch(2L)

         response.status == OK.value()
         response.contentType.contains('application/json')
         response.contentType == 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

         content.webId == 2L
     }
 }
```

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Text must not be null or empty

my Java Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/lookups")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LookupController
{

     @NonNull
     private final LookupService lookupService;

     @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     @ResponseBody
     public ResponseEntity<Page<LookupModel>> list(@RequestParam(required = false ) Long lookupId,  Pageable pageable)
     {
         return ResponseEntity.ok(lookupService.fetchAll(lookupId, 
 pageable));
     }
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: this doesn't look like Java, what language/framework is this? Maybe edit your tags accordingly

Comment: It doesn't look like you're sharing enough of the code... how is it invoked? What is the value passed to it? Also note the language and framework in the title.

Comment: `mockMvc` will not for unit test, you need integration tests

Comment: @sotix updated the code

Comment: @dagelf I have updated the code. Is it enough to understand.

Comment: @Deadpool You mean dont use MockMvc for unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add dependency to spock-spring

```
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.0-M1-groovy-2.5')
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M1-groovy-2.5')

testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
   exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
```

and then you can do the Integration test with spring like this:

```java
import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest
class LookupControllerTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc

    @SpringBean
    private LookupService lookupService = Mock()

    def "should return a single lookup record when test hits the URL and parses JSON output"() {
        when:
        def response = mockMvc
                .perform(get('/api/lookups/')
                        .param("lookupId", "2")
                        .param("page", "0")
                        .param("size", "0"))
                .andReturn()
                .response

        then:
        response.status == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    }
}
```

all you need is to specify your Mock service now.